# Got error invalid parameters from the chrome extension doc

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to do a simple extension that put text from a page into google search in another tab
When I try to execute the script from the [google doc](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/) , I get this error :
[image]

I have this code in popup.js (I'm still learning chrome extension dev)

```
var getTheText = ()=>{
    textfromtab= document.querySelector("p.maintext").textContent;
        textfromtab= textfromtab.replace(/["']/g, " ");
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: "https://www.google.com/search?q="+textfromtab
        });
    
    }

async function getCurrentTab() {
  let queryOptions = { active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true };

  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
  console.log(tab);
  return tab.id;
}

function gettabqu(){
    const tabId = getCurrentTab();
    chrome.scripting.executeScript(
    {
      target: {tabId: tabId, allFrames: true},
      func: getTheText,
    });
}
var textfromtab = "";
```

this is the permissions from my manifest.json:

```
"permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting","tabs"],
```

and this is what I get when I do a `console.log(tab.id)`
[image]

Comment: It complains that the tabId you are specifying here, `target: {tabId: tabId`, is not an integer as it should be, but an object.

Comment: On an unrelated note: Why are you using "jfkqzlfjl" as a variable name? Variable names made up of random letters make your code unnecessarily difficult to understand.

Comment: @ThomasMueller yes sorry, I renamed the var. It's just that I type fast and used to type anything to name my var when I'm learning new stuff to get poc faster. bad habbit

Comment: @CBroe yes ? but when I debug tab.id I do get an integer.

Comment: Please paste all text into your question. Don't use images to show error messages, console output, etc.

Comment: it's ok to use images to show errors. It's pretty common. Thank you for your very good answer, I have marked as solved

Comment: @Richard "it's ok to use images to show errors. It's pretty common" --- It's frowned upon on SO: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) > DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. --- But SO doesn't exactly go out of its way to tell newbies about it: [Where are new users supposed to learn that they should show code and error messages as text, not as images?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415324/where-are-new-users-supposed-to-learn-that-they-should-show-code-and-error-messa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in:

```
const tabId = getCurrentTab();
```

getCurrentTab() is an asnyc function.
Asnyc functions always return promises.
So `target.tabId` is a promise, when it should be an integer.

Solution:

```
const tabId = await getCurrentTab();
```

But that means you also need to make `gettabqu()` an async function, or you won't be able to use `await` inside it.